# curved navigation bar make it tappable

Tags: flutter, touch, navigationbar

I want to use this Navigation bar code , and it's work correctly but the problem is i don't know how to make item tappable to each item show the dart file that i want?
for example: add: show add.dart, list :show list.dart and ...

here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';

 void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: BottomNavBar()));

  class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
  }

  class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
   int _page = 0;
   GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
      key: _bottomNavigationKey,
      index: 0,
      height: 50.0,
      items: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.add, size: 30),
        Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
        Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
        Icon(Icons.call_split, size: 30),
        Icon(Icons.perm_identity, size: 30),
      ],
      color: Colors.white,
      buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      onTap: (index) {
        setState(() {
          _page = index;
        });
      },
    ),
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_page.toString(), textScaleFactor: 10.0),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Go To Page of index 1'),
              onPressed: () {
                final CurvedNavigationBarState navBarState =
                    _bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
                navBarState.setPage(1);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `index`, to show the page you need.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'page1.dart'
import 'page2.dart'

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: BottomNavBar()));

class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _pageIndex = 0;
  GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

  List pages = [
    MyRoute(
      iconData: Icons.add,
      page: Page1(),
    ),
    MyRoute(
      iconData: Icons.compare_arrows,
      page: Page2(),
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        key: _bottomNavigationKey,
        index: 0,
        height: 50.0,
        items: pages
            .map((p) => Icon(
                  p.iconData,
                  size: 30,
                ))
            .toList(),
        color: Colors.white,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _pageIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      body: pages[_pageIndex].page,
    );
  }
}

class MyRoute {
  final IconData iconData;
  final Widget page;

  MyRoute({this.iconData, this.page});
}
```

`page1.dart`

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text('Page1'));
  }
}
```

`page2.dart`

```
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text('Page2'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work in my way, because i have 4 dart file that i want to show them and when i try to do this it doesn't show the dart file's

Comment: You just need to import these files.

Comment: I have try it in another project and it's worked nicely and thanks for your help , But now the problem is this code are in bottombar.dart and i want to show it in my main file or call it

Comment: the Scaffold is on main.dart and in this code's i have start from widget CurvedNavigationBar

Comment: Works for me! 
I used it this way: 

int currentIndex = 0;
List pages = const [HomePage(), CartPage(), ProfilePage()];
body: pages[currentIndex],
onTap: (index) {
  setState(() => currentIndex = index);
},

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this tutorial which will give you the idea [Flutter curved navigation bar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmwpAhG5UMo)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this flutter plugin** `curved_navigation_bar 0.3.1`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: BottomNavBar()));

class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _page = 0;
  GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          key: _bottomNavigationKey,
          index: 0,
          height: 50.0,
          items: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.add, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.call_split, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.perm_identity, size: 30),
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
          buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _page = index;
            });
          },
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(_page.toString(), textScaleFactor: 10.0),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Go To Page of index 1'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    final CurvedNavigationBarState navBarState =
                        _bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
                    navBarState.setPage(1);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```